# How to get all possible combinations of 1 and 2 in length of n that 2s are not besides together?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to get all possible combinations of 1 and 2 that 2s are not besides together.
for example, if n=3, then I want a list like this:

```
    111
    121
    211
    112
    212
    ...
```

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Simple approach: `list(filter(lambda p: "22" not in p, map("".join, itertools.product("12", repeat=n))))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`, then filter out the `22`:

```
from itertools import product

values, n = "12", 3
result = [r for x in product(values, repeat=n)
          if "22" not in (r := "".join(x))]
print(result)  # ['111', '112', '121', '211', '212']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product 
    
N = 6
n_prod = list(product(['1','2'],repeat=N))
[x for x in list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), n_prod)) if '22' not in x]
```

But maybe it's too overweight...
Maybe better use

```
from random import choice
choice([1,2])
```